# Adding headers in WP7 WebClient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

I'm using code from other c# app and I can see that in WP7 doesn't support headers. How to change that code to work in WP7

```
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, header_auth);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add Headers in WP7 like this,

```
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = header_auth;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Didn't know what to do with HttpRequestHeader.Authorization at first. Now it's working well.